# Insert Sequential Numbers in Insert query use Select query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I Want to Copy some Data between two Data Bases, so I use an Insert query like the following:

```
INSERT INTO [NewDB].[MyTable]
(
[FirstName],
[LastName],
[Number]
)
(
SELECT [ST].[FirstName], [ST].[LastName], **SequentialNumber**
FROM [SourceDB].[SourceTable] AS [ST]
);
GO
```

But the new table have a new unique int not null column named Number as you see, so how can I insert sequential numbers (actually 10 digits number) with use the following script, Some thing like 1234567891, 1234567892, ... ,  Does any one have any idea?

Comment: So `Number` is already an identity column? Do you want to insert whilst letting it do its incrementinh thing or do you want to force it to accept the new sequential values you provide in the SELECT?

Comment: @Alex K. The `Number` is not identity and I have some reason to don't do that, I just want some Sequential number for the data of Source Db and in New Data the `Number` have a special format inserted by app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` function, e.g.:

```
INSERT INTO [NewDB].[MyTable]
(
    [FirstName],
    [LastName],
    [Number]
)

SELECT [ST].[FirstName], [ST].[LastName], ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [ST].[FirstName])
FROM [SourceDB].[SourceTable] AS [ST]
```

Comment: Actually i want a 10 digit numbers : like 1234567890 and 1234567891, do you have any idea?

Comment: @Saeid, Then simply: `10000000000 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [ST].[FirstName])` :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT 
        [ST].[FirstName], 
        [ST].[LastName], 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [ST].[FirstName]) AS rowNbr
    FROM 
        [SourceDB].[SourceTable] AS [ST]
)
INSERT INTO [NewDB].[MyTable]
(
    [FirstName],
    [LastName],
    [Number]
)
SELECT
    CTE.[FirstName],
    CTE.[LastName]
    1234567890+(CTE.rowNbr-1)
FROM
    CTE
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
INSERT INTO [MyTable]
(
[FirstName],
[LastName],
[Number]
)

SELECT [ST].[FirstName], [ST].[LastName], (select max(number)+1 from [MyTable])
FROM [SourceTable] AS [ST]
```

in case you don't have records on `MyTable` you will need a case on the select to deal with a NULL value